# Computing the css style attributes that a given html tag has

Tags: python, html, css, parsing

I would like to know how to compute which css style attributes a given html tag has, given the css stylesheet as well. I am thinking of something similar to using xpath to select html nodes, but using selectors to pick css attributes instead. All I have found searching are css parsers but I can't figure out a way, if any, for doing what I have explained with them. If not possible, is there a python library that can do this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically, or are you trying to just debug your code?

Comment: Note that the computed style is dependent on pseudo classes such as :hover and :visited. To programmatically compute the style attributes you would have to exclude those rules.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to evaluate the background color of a given tag, so yes it is programmatically computing or finding those attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern: http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-web#DOM

Comment: I don't see what difference it would make by using those parsers rather than lxml, which I'm using currently

Answer (score 0):

well because the css style attribute has a definite format you can do..

```
var styleValues = $("selector").attr('style').split(';')
```

Comment: I would like a python solution if possible, although this can work as a last resort